# C++ read and write information with [] overload

Tags: c++11

I have the following class :

```
class MyPoint
{
    public:
    
        // Constructor
        MyPoint(double, double, double);

        // Destructor
        virtual ~MyPoint(){};

    protected:

    private:
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;

};
```

I would like to overload the operator [] to read and write data.

Something like:

```
myPoint[0] will return x
myPoint[1] will return y
myPoint[2] will return z
```

And if I do:

```
myPoint[0]=2 will set x = 2
myPoint[1]=3 will set y = 3
myPoint[z]=4 will set z = 4
```

For the first part I have:

```
double operator[](int entry)
{
    if (entry==0)
        return x;
    else if(entry==1)
        return y;
    else if(entry==2)
        return z;
}
```

For the second I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the member variable by-reference instead of by-value so that you have an `lvalue` you can assign to:

```
double& operator[](int entry)
//    ^
//    |
{
    if (entry==0)
        return x;
    else if(entry==1)
        return y;
    else if(entry==2)
        return z;
}
```

Note that you don't currently return anything when passed anything other than 0, 1, or 2 and thus exhibit undefined behavior. You should probably raise an exception if anything else is considered invalid:

```
double& operator[](int entry)
{
    if (entry==0)
        return x;
    else if(entry==1)
        return y;
    else if(entry==2)
        return z;

    throw std::out_of_range("unsupported entry value: " + std::to_string(entry));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your `operator[]` returns the current value of x, y or z *by value*. Thus, if you write

```cpp
myPoint[0] = 2;
```

this would attempt to make a copy of the value of `myPoint.x` and then try to modify it while the original value in `myPoint` is not changed. This does not work on a conceptual level, and it also does not compile, since the assignment doesn't make any sense, just as writing `4 = 2` does not make any sense. The left side of the `=` operator can not be changed.

What you want to do is make your `operator[]` return *by reference*. You can achieve this by changing the return type from `double` to `double&`, giving the signature:

```cpp
double& operator[](int entry);
```

This way, you will change the value of the double referenced, which is the double in your object.

You can find further tutorials on the internet, e.g. [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/returning_values_by_reference.htm)

The point clcto pointed out is important, you should have that in mind: If you use your `operator[]` with any other index than 0, 1 or 2, the control flow will not end with a return statement, which is undefined behavior. You may want to check this on runtime and throw an exception if this happens.